# Should I flag a very old question for migration?

Tags: support, migration

I came across a question from 2011 that, were it not so old, I would flag for migration to Music Fans.<sup>1</sup> Is there a rule or rule-of-thumb for this?

- The question has been here a long time, and it's not hurting anyone. Leave it be. Don't create extra work for the mods.
- Our priority is to keep the site as well organized as possible, and that's a team effort. Flag anything you feel appropriate so it can get checked out.
- Something else?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Is there some symbolic meaning to breaking all the instruments during or at the end of your music video?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/is-there-some-symbolic-meaning-to-breaking-all-the-instruments-during-or-at-the). It was last active in 2016.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible, not even for ♦ moderators, to migrate a question older than 60 days. See the FAQ: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/295232)

Comment: The question in question I'm going to leave as is, since it's not egregiously off-topic. Is there a general take on flagging or voting to close old questions?

Comment: If it's not done en masse, it's usually OK to flag them. Not sure if Music.SE has different rules.

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel - We have the same rules